# How to find loops in a network

Tags: sql

I am a new in this field and need help,  how to code using SQL spatial a function that retrieve loops in a network.The input, flag: Geography and barrier: Geography  and   two spatial tables, first one will list the edges(edgekey, from_junction, to_junction, polyline) and the second table containing juctions(junctionkey, point).

The output will be a spatial table containing (edgekey, polykey,  from_junction, to_junction, polyline), a single polygon  will have the same polykey for each from_junction  to_junction value.

Comment: The input you describe does not suffice to detect actual *polygons*: loops in an abstract network can be transected by other parts of the network. It sounds rather like you are asking to dissect a region into polygons bounded by a given set of arcs or polylines. If that's the case, you really need to be applying a "geoprocessing" operation, rather than a database query. Perhaps that will set you on the right track to getting a solution.

Comment: The function should return a set of polyline features with edgeKey not a polygons

Comment: this part of Utility Network AnalysisTrace upstream elements
• Trace downstream elements
• Upstream accumulation cost
• Find a path upstream
• Find common ancestors of a set of locations on the
network
• Find connected elements
• Find disconnected elements
• Find multiple-path loops
• Find all paths between locations